# Why is this Excel VBA code for creating a list through data validation not working?

Tags: vba, excel

This is the entire code:

```
Dim Total_rows_Dash7 As Long
Dim Total_rows_Input7 As Long
Dim i7 As Long

Total_rows_Dash7 = Workbooks("Hourly Production Monitoring.xlsm").Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
Total_rows_Input7 = Workbooks("Hourly Production Monitoring.xlsm").Worksheets("Input").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

For i7 = 2 To Total_rows_Input7
     With Worksheets("Input").Range("E" & i7).Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="='Dashboard'!$A$2:$A$25"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
Next i7
```

The part that errors is this portion:

```
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="='Dashboard'!$A$2:$A$25"
```

I have also tried:

```
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="='Dashboard'!$A$2:$A$" & Total_rows_Dash7 & ""
```

The error is:

[image]

I've been stuck for a while now I don't know why it's not working.

**SOLUTION (Youtube video):**
[Solution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_OiklMpAmK8)

To reference another worksheet using data validation, you cannot use the normal way of referencing a cell or range (e.g. `='WorksheetName'!A2:A25`) on some cases (but most of the time you can with no problem). If you do have a problem referencing the standard way, you will instead have to select the items you want to include in a list and then rename that selection through the upper left box in the spreadsheet. Then you have to reference it by typing the name of the selection on the Source Box of the data validation: **=NameOfSelection** (Note no punctuation marks of any sort and no cell/range reference)

Then to dynamically update it. You can use the macro to determine how to dynamically name a list of items based on your own criteria.

**Working Code:**

```
Dim Total_rows_Dash7 As Long
Dim Total_rows_Input7 As Long
Dim i7 As Long

Total_rows_Dash7 = Workbooks("Hourly Production Monitoring.xlsm").Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
Total_rows_Input7 = Workbooks("Hourly Production Monitoring.xlsm").Worksheets("Input").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="JobTicketNo", RefersToR1C1:= _
        "=Dashboard!R2C1:R" & Total_rows_Dash7 & "C1"

For i7 = 2 To Total_rows_Input7
     With Workbooks("Hourly Production Monitoring.xlsm").Worksheets("Input").Range("E" & i7).Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=JobTicketNo"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
Next i7
```

Below is the error when using usual way of referencing:
[image: Error]

Comment: Do you only have one workbook open, i.e. "Hourly Production Monitoring.xlsm"?  If you have another one open, does the other one have an "Input" sheet but no "Dashboard" sheet?

Comment: I only have 1 workbook of that name open and both worksheets are present. I kept checking for spelling errors and other parts of my code for an hour :/.  I found the solution already. It's due to the unique way of referencing cells/ranges in data validation. I placed it on the original post for others to see

Comment: FWIW - recording a macro generates `Formula1:="=Dashboard!$A$2:$A$25"`, and re-running the macro after it is recorded works for me.  Editing the macro to use `Formula1:="='Dashboard'!$A$2:$A$25"` (i.e. with the apostrophes) still allows it to work.

Comment: Weird. I recall also that it worked using that method but suddenly it stopped working. I tried doing that outside the VBE and doing it manually to make sure that it was not some coding problem and it still errors if I use apostrophe version to reference another worksheet to create a list.

Comment: I added a photo in the original post. Not sure if I did anything wrong in the reference

Comment: Have you tried using the cell selector at the end of the Source field to select the relevant cells, rather than typing the formula in?  (Can't see why it would be any different, but I also can't see why it is failing at all.)

Comment: I can't press another worksheet while on the source field but only select cells on the current worksheet. It's really weird. Are you able to press on another worksheet on your end?

Comment: Yes, once the "selector" is activated I can click on another sheet and then select cells in that other sheet.  Try creating a dummy workbook with just two sheets in it (one called "Dashboard") and see whether you can set a data validation on the non-Dashboard sheet.  I'm thinking that your workbook is corrupted in some way.

Comment: Or maybe you have an add-in that is blocking it in some way??

Comment: I'm using Excel 2007 just to note. The excel versions around the office and at my home vary. Perhaps that's why. Maybe excel 2007 has limited functionality which is why it works at my home and not here.

Comment: I have to call it a night now, so I will have to let you play with it yourself.  I'll be interested to see if you come up with anything - but what you are doing **should** work.

Comment: @YowE3K thanks for the help as always. If it works on your end at least we now have 2 solutions for those who encounter a problem (perhaps on older versions of excel)

Comment: I'm 99.9% certain that even in 2007 I was using data validation on other sheets.  (That's the standard way I used to set it up - have the ranges of valid values on one sheet, and then use them in the main worksheets.)

Comment: I see. I guess there's something blocking it off i'll try it when i get to my home pc.

Comment: I tried doing that on another PC with Excel 2016 and I can select different worksheets with no problem at all. However, creating a new workbook on this PC with Excel 2007 still cannot select a different worksheet. Perhaps its in the version or some other cause but eitherway I was able to work around it.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
With Worksheets("Input").Range("E" & i7).Validation
```

might be struggling with the correct workbook to be working with.

Qualify that name via..

```
With Workbooks("xxx").Worksheets("Input").Range("E" & i7).Validation
```

Comment: `With Workbooks("Hourly Production Monitoring.xlsm").Worksheets("Input").Range("E" & i7).Validation` I tried this. Same error

Comment: Are you deleting exisiting validation in your `.Delete` line? Does it work if you removed the `.Delete`?

Comment: Okay I believe I know what the problem is. It's the string: '='Dashboard'!$A$2:$A$25" it's weird. It used to work with this same code but suddenly not working anymore. I tried it out in the data validation button itself in excel

Comment: I don't understand it seems data validation cannot reference other worksheets. Although i'm almost sure that I am able to reference them before or am I wrong

Comment: I'm not sure you need the apostrophes in your sheet ref. Try...`Formula1:="=Dashboard!$A$2:$A$" & Total_rows_Dash7 & ""`

Comment: Tried that it's still not working. Referencing in Data Validation is quite different I think I found a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_OiklMpAmK8

Comment: My problem is that I need the list to dynamically update so it's a problem if I follow the video alone

Comment: Okay I found the solution... So happy after 2 hours

Comment: Let us know for future VBA coders with similar issues